# What color is obtained from lighting and color materials in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, colors, lighting

Hi i have one question.

I'm trying to understand lighting and material in OpenGL.

but I do not know how the lighting affects the color and reflection of an object.

Here's the light formula I've found:

```
result Light = ambient + diffuse * (intensity) + specular
```

and here's an example usage:

```
ambient = 64,64,64

diffuse = 192,192,192

specular = 32,32,32 

intentisy = 0.5 

Light = 64 + 192*0.5+ 32 = 192

Result Light = (192,192,192)
```

Here's how it comes together to form the final output:

```
Object Color = (Or,Og,Ob)

Material reflect = (Mr,Mg,Mb)

Real Color = (Or * Mr , Og * Mg ,Ob * Mb )
```

For my question,

I do not know how the "result light" affects the "real color"?
More specifically: How the final pixel output comes to fruition using all the light, material and object color inputs.

Comment: Thk you!! I know that also i atudy shader too ,but our organization use these. So i need learn both old gl and new gl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little ambiguous because **real** can range from physical based rendering techniques to differed shading with various custom lighting shaders.

Depending on the "Material" we'll have a different equation which uses "Result Light".

Here are some basic materials:

[image]

**Ambient Lighting**:

```
float ambientStrength = 0.1f;
vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

vec3 result = ambient * objectColor;
color = vec4(result, 1.0f);
```

**Diffuse Lighting**:

```
in vec3 FragPos;  // input
vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);

vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);

vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse) * objectColor;
color = vec4(result, 1.0f);
```

**Specular Lighting**:

```
float specularStrength = 0.5f;
vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm); 


float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor; 

vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * objectColor;
color = vec4(result, 1.0f);
```

**Combined Phong**:

Recycle code from above.

[Source](https://learnopengl.com/#!Lighting/Basic-Lighting)

Comment: (Or * Mr , Og * Mg ,Ob * Mb ), 
I thought that formula was a color calculated when there was light. and i did not use shader. only use fixed pipeline, like glLightfv. Is not ambient color and real color different?  i tihnk Real Color is not apply lightning and pixel Color is calculated real color and result lighting. is it wrong?

Comment: @성정민 I must've misunderstood. Updating answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh my god.. Thk you !!! I really understand all of these. Could you plz one more question???? Object color above shader source already calculated by fomular( Or * Mr , Og * Mg ,Ob * Mb ). is that right????

Comment: @성정민 No probs, try to clarify the question so it doesn't get downvoted. I can help you review it.

Comment: @성정민 The formula "( Or * Mr , Og * Mg ,Ob * Mb )." is an oversimplification as its highly dependent on the material to determine how the "object color" and "material color" are multiplied or integrated with one another.

Comment: Oh... I understan that. In summary, Material and origin color is complex. So that cant be expresssed only one fomular. i'll more study about that. sorry my bad english.. And thank you :)

Comment: @성정민 Of course and don't worry. I'll try to clarify your question. Keep at it ;)